# How does this game loop actually work?

Tags: javascript, game-loop

I read this playfulJS post, about ray-casting:
http://www.playfuljs.com/a-first-person-engine-in-265-lines/

It looks really interested, so I decided to look at his javascript. I am no expert in javascript, so I quickly got lost.

It's the game loop "object" that really gets me.
I simply don't understand how it works.
From the code:

```
function GameLoop() {
        this.frame = this.frame.bind(this);
        this.lastTime = 0;
        this.callback = function() {};
      }

      GameLoop.prototype.start = function(callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        requestAnimationFrame(this.frame);
      };

      GameLoop.prototype.frame = function(time) {
        var seconds = (time - this.lastTime) / 1000;
        this.lastTime = time;
        if (seconds < 0.2) this.callback(seconds);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.frame);
      };

var loop = new GameLoop();

      loop.start(function frame(seconds) {
        map.update(seconds);
        player.update(controls.states, map, seconds);
        camera.render(player, map);
      });
```

Now, what really confuses me here, is this bind stuff and how this actually loops.

I am guessing, that if less than 0.2 seconds have passed, since the last time the loop was run, it simply goes back to re-check the time. If more than 0.2 seconds have passed, it leaves the frame function, and executes the 3 lines in the loop.

But, if this is true, then how does the loop.start() get called again?
And what on earth is the meaning of `this.frame = this.frame.bind(this);`?

I've looked up prototypes bind() but I really don't understand it.

Comment: Are you familiar with [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) programming in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your guess is a bit backwards.  The `start` prototype of `GameLoop` takes a callback function that represents the core update steps of the application; in this case, player and map updates, and drawing.  The `frame` function will run this callback function if the time elapsed since the last frame is less than `0.2` seconds.  I'm assuming that `requestAnimationFrame` is a higher level API call to refresh the window.

Now, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) takes a callback which represents the function it should run as part of the window refresh.  The writer of this code wanted this callback to be associated with a particular object, so that it could have access to internal variables such as `this.callback` and `this.lastTime`.  In order to do that, the callback provided to `requestAnimationFrame` must be bound to a specific instance of `GameLoop`, and that is what [`this.frame.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) accomplishes.

To put it another way, the call to `bind` establishes that the `this` object in the prototype `frame` function will refer to a specific instance of `GameLoop`; the one provided in the call to `bind`.